# How can I constrain a predefined replacement-function to selected text?

Tags: evil, replace, selection

When using `replace-string` from the <kbd>M-x</kbd> while having some text selected, it only operates on that selection (specifically, on an Evil visual selection, in my case). However, if I put the same replacement in a function in my `init.el`, like

```
(defun my-custom-replace ()
    "Replaces 'foo' with 'bar'."
    (interactive)
    (replace-string "foo" "bar") )
```

it always seems to modify the entire buffer instead. How can I get this to respect the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult the documentation for `replace-string` (you get the doc with <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `replace-string` <kbd>RET</kbd>). The Section on the arguments START and END clearly says how to reproduce the interactive behavior in elisp functions:

> Operates on the region between START and END (if both are nil, from point
>   to the end of the buffer).  Interactively, if Transient Mark mode is
>   enabled and the mark is active, operates on the contents of the region;
>   otherwise from point to the end of the buffer’s accessible portion.

So the corrected version of your code is:

```el
(defun my-custom-replace ()
    "Replaces 'foo' with 'bar'."
    (interactive)
    (replace-string "foo" "bar" nil (region-beginning) (region-end)) )
```